# Rewrite htaccess to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

Im setting up a plugin. Their troubleshoot guide says i should add this to my htaccess. My server runs nginx, so im really not sure how to convert this to nginx setting:

```
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
```

I have been trying a few things, but nothing has really worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which folder would it be lying? And what is the final request going too look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending how you are putting it, but the rule would changes to something like below

```
location /api {
  rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest break;
}
```

But if your `api.php` is not in the document root folder, then you would need few changes to this

Comment: Yes break is only needed if you add more rules